# Texture doesn't apply correctly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

Does anyone know why this texture stretches like this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have not unwrapped your mesh at all or correctly, just tab into *edit mode*, press <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>U</kbd> and select the unwrap option. If your mesh`s texture is still messy in that case, follow any one of the three methods given below. Also, press <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and press the *rotation and scale* option in the pop-up menu to zero out the object's rotation and scale as *@kay777* said.

*1. Cube projection*

[image]

Tab into *edit mode*, press <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>U</kbd> and select *cube projection* *(most suitable for objects which look like cubes).*

*2. Smart UV project*

[image]

Tab into *edit mode*, press <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>U</kbd> and select the *Smart UV Project* then a pop-up menu will show up, press the ok button.

*3. Lightmap pack>follow active quads*

[image]

First select a *random quadrilateral* face (a face with four edges) in your mesh, press <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>U</kbd>, select *light map pack*, press <kbd>U</kbd> again and select the *Follow Active quads*.

Comment: I tried everything except for Smart UV Project because blender crashes as soon as I press the button. It may be because it is a very long tunnel:
https://imgur.com/a/o9HCuVU

Comment: In that case please add the blend file so I can check out the problem myself

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for offering to look at it. I stripped down the project, you can clearly see that the texture stretch happens where I stretched the faces of the tunnel to make it land flat on the ground. https://pasteall.org/blend/aa7e9425850e421ea3c8ff82f2fb09e8

Comment: Hi there again is there any reason for a gap in your mesh? Take a look at it
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEQ-ElTG-zm2_UJ0mriEVqUXVO8FhMVQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There was initially but I don't really need it anymore. Do you think it is that? Is it hard to re-attach those faces?

Comment: Maybe try adding an edge loop to subdivide that part?I think that`s the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to *Apply Scale* (<kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) - Also You should do a *Smart UV projection* and then connect the UV node into the mapping.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying! I tried that but Smart UV Projects causes blender to crash. Could it be because of how long the tunnel is?

https://imgur.com/a/o9HCuVU

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

[image]

Select your tunnel and then press **'Shift+H'** to hide every other object in your scene except the tunnel, tab into edit mode, press **'A'** to select all faces/vertices/edges and then press **'M'** and select the **'Merge by distance'** option in the bottom so that all overlapping edges/vertices/faces are removed.

**Step 2 (optional):**

[image]

If you want to check out the UV mapping of the object just create a simple checker in blender by copying these nodes. This step is optional and not necessary in this method.

**Step 3:**

[image]

Go to **'Material preview mode'**, tab into edit mode, press 'A', press **'U'** and then unwrap, now you should notice that the unwrap is not good as the texture breaks. So press **'A'** to select all the faces in edit mode again, press **'U'** and select the **'Smart UV project'** option.

Comment: Ok so this was very helpful! The Texture checker appears to work perfectly but when I try to do the same things with the material I chose, I still get that stretched out thing. It stretches exactly in the portion where the faces are "longer".

https://imgur.com/a/HuvtfdD

Comment: Oh ok could you maybe share a picture of the 'stretching part' with the texture.

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/A2WtP1n Thanks!